# Split string to CamelCase words and also uppercase acronymns

Tags: javascript, regex

Given a string containing CamelCase and also uppercase acronymns e.g. 'ManualABCTask';

How can it be split to a string with a space between all words and acronyms in a less wordy way?

I had the following process:

```
let initial = 'ManualABCTask'
//Split on single upper case followed by any number of lower case:
.split(/(['A-Z'][a-z]*)/g)
//the returned array includes empty string entries e.g. ["", "", "Manual", "A", "", "B", "", "C","", "Task", ""] so remove these:
.filter(x => x != '');

//When joining the array, the acronymn uppercase single letters have a space e.g. 'Manual A B C Task' so instead, reduce and add space only if array entry has more than one character
 let word = initial.reduce((prevVal,currVal) => {
    return  (currVal.length == 1) ? prevVal + currVal  : prevVal + ' ' + currVal + ' ';
}, '');
```

This does the job on the combinations it needs to e.g:

- 'ManualABCTask' => 'Manual ABC Task'
- 'ABCManualTask' => 'ABC Manual Task'
- 'ABCManualDEFTask' => 'ABC Manual DEF Task'

But it was a lot of code for the job done and surely could be handled in the initial regex.

I was experimenting while writing the question and with a tweak to the regex, got it down to one line, big improvement! So posting anyway with solution.

My regex know how isn't great so this could maybe be improved on still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know near to nothing about `JavaScript` but i had a bash at it:

```
let initial = 'ManualABCTask'
initial = initial.replace(/([A-Z][a-z]+)/g, ' $1 ').trim();
```

Comment: That is concise

Comment: @JMP, thanks. Was fun to work on and explore JavaScript a bit. Hope it does the job for you.

Answer (score 1):

There 2 groups: starting from head letter with following lowercases, and starting from head letter until next letter isn't lowercase:

```js
find = new RegExp(
    "(" +
    "[A-Z][a-z]+" +  // Group starting from head letter with following lowercases
    "|" +
    "[A-Z]+(?![a-z])" +  // Group with head letters until next letter isn't lowercase:
    ")",
    "g"
)
initial = 'ManualABCTask'.split(find)
```

Comment: Yep that does the trick too. I'll have to look properly into how its doing it, thanks.

Comment: Without this negative check `(?![a-z])` group with head-letters get one extra letter like `ABCT`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in post, changed to handle in regex:

```
  initial = 'ManualABCTask'.split(/(['A-Z']{2,99})(['A-Z'][a-z]*)/g).join(' ');
```

Group any concurrent upper characters with length of 2 to 99 to get the acronyms, and any single upper character followed by any number of lower to get the other words. Join with space.

Comment: You should be able to use `{2,}` without an upper bound.

Comment: Thought  that would get picked up! I used incorrect syntax originally so stuck the 99 in. Didn't realise it just needed empty after the comma whch seems obvious now. Thanks.